# Can journals share information about your submission?

Tags: publications, journals, privacy

Can journals share information about your submission or for that matter your entire submission at will? Is that fair game? Is this a varying practice based on who you submit to?

Is the general idea that the implications of sharing the notes and related content is trivial?

Comment: I reopened the question. I can't parse the last sentence, though, you might want to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no, journals cannot arbitrarily share your submission with others—at least not before it's been accepted.

However, they *can* share your submission with:

- Reviewers, so that the peer-review process can be completed
- Other staff members within the publisher, which can be useful when a paper is submitted to the "wrong" section of a journal, or to the wrong journal, but is otherwise acceptable for publication.

Once the paper has been accepted and appropriate copyrights assigned, though, they can do more or less whatever they normally do in their publication and advertising process.

Comment: Really? I'm surprised - I'd have thought that a journal, having received a submission, could legally circulate it to any other journal that was contained within the same corporate entity. If you submit to Nature, couldn't the Nature editor then kick it downstairs to, say, Nature Communications or Nature Methods?

Comment: Purely for informational purposes and nothing more, . . . is there a link where say APS journals receive submissions. A portal say of sorts where a paper is received via the web, and perhaps something similar for nature? Again conversational  . . . no intentions but I think it might benefit someone.